# Move the button horizontally in Grid of WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, .net-6.0

My WPF app has many buttons and they are ordered on 1 row as the below picture:
[image]

**What I want**: When user click the left arrow, button will move left 1 column as below and and vice versa for the right arrow

[image]

Could I do this in WPF? Any help would be appreciated on this.

Comment: Is the number of buttons fixed?

Comment: You can use a grid and have the buttons created in the behind code. Add these buttons to the grid by using grid.children.add(button1) on the click of right arrow.

Comment: Hi @Arki99, yes buttons name is fixed. I will try it according you said. Tks you so much

Comment: Add the buttons in a ScrollViewer and hide the horizontal scroll, then when the user click on the arrows set the HorizontalOffsetProperty based on the width and space between the buttons

Comment: `Grid.SetColumn(button, Grid.GetColumn(button) - 1);`

Comment: @Clemens tks you. It worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to adjust the size of the control based on your view.

```
private void leftBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    scrollView.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(scrollView.HorizontalOffset - 220);
}

private void rightBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    scrollView.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(scrollView.HorizontalOffset + 220);

}

 <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button x:Name="leftBtn" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" Click="leftBtn_Click">Left</Button>
    <ScrollViewer Width="660" x:Name="scrollView" Grid.Column="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Margin="10" Width="200">Button1</Button>
                <Button Margin="10" Width="200">Button2</Button>
                <Button Margin="10" Width="200">Button3</Button>
                <Button Margin="10" Width="200">Button4</Button>
                <Button Margin="10" Width="200">Button5</Button>
                <Button Margin="10" Width="200">Button6</Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    <Button x:Name="rightBtn" Grid.Column="2" Margin="5" Click="rightBtn_Click">Right</Button>
    
</Grid>
```

Comment: tks you so much. It's really the easiest way to do